# Find time interval with maximum count in big data

Tags: r, time, data.table, time-series

I have a huge dataframe with millions of email addresses and their open time. Below is the subset of my dataframe.

[image]

```
dput(droplevels(data))
structure(list(email_address_hash = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26", 
"00198ee5364d73796e0e352f1d2576f8e8fa99db", "35c0ef2c2a804b44564fd4278a01ed25afd887f8"
), class = "factor"), open_times = c(" 04:39:24 10:39:43", " 21:12:04 07:05:23 06:31:24", 
" 09:57:20 19:00:09")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("email_address_hash", 
"open_times"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000007b60788>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

The structure of my data frame is

```
str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ email_address_hash: Factor w/ 36231 levels "00012aec4ca3fa6f2f96cf97fc2a3440eacad30e",..: 2 16 7632
 $ open_times        : chr  " 04:39:24 10:39:43" " 21:12:04 07:05:23 06:31:24" " 09:57:20 19:00:09"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I want to achieve these two goals

**Aim :-**

**1) Starts from 00:00:00 hours and take an interval of an hour and count the number of entries per customers I got. Suppose for our first case open_times for first row is 04:39:24 and 10:39:43 . So it gets one count b/w 4:00:00- 5:00:00 and one count b/w 10:00:00 and 11:00:00 and zero count for all the others interval like b/w 00:00:00 and 01:00:00 and so on.I want only first two counts which has maximum numbers of entries . In this case it is 4:00:00-5:00:00 and 10:00:00-11:00:00  and their respective count in other columns**

**2) Is it possible to change the time interval from 1 hour to 1.5 hrs or 2hrs for the same case ?**

In order to provide more explanation below is the image of my desired output
[image]
Please suggest me some efficient way of solving this problem as I am having a big data. Please let me know if something is unclear to you instead of down voting my question.

Comment: @akrun can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

for starters restructure the data to a long format that you can use for summarizing the data. This example uses `dplyr` package.

Study how to work with times and dates, to make it more sophisticated. I just seperate the different components of time out of the strings.

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

norm <- df %>% mutate(times=trimws(open_times)) %>% 
  separate(times,c('t1','t2','t3','t4'), sep = " ") %>%
  gather(key, value, -email_address_hash,-open_times) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  separate(value, into = c('hr','min','sec'), sep=":") 


norm %>%
  group_by(hr) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

results in

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
hr     n
<chr> <int>
04     1
06     1
07     1
09     1
10     1
19     1
21     1
```

You can calculate groups using different intervals like so:

```
interval <- 90

norm %>% 
  mutate(minutes = 60*as.numeric(hr)+as.numeric(min),
  group = (minutes-minutes%%interval)/interval) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

I calculate the minutes since midnight, and use that value to make groups of 90 minutes (1.5 hours).

This is the structure of normalized data:

```
> str(norm)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  6 variables:
  $ email_address_hash: Factor w/ 3 levels "0004eca7b8bed22aaf4b320ad602505fe9fa9d26",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 2
$ open_times        : chr  " 04:39:24 10:39:43" " 21:12:04 07:05:23 06:31:24" " 09:57:20 19:00:09" " 04:39:24 10:39:43" ...
$ key               : chr  "t1" "t1" "t1" "t2" ...
$ hr                : chr  "04" "21" "09" "10" ...
$ min               : chr  "39" "12" "57" "39" ...
$ sec               : chr  "24" "04" "20" "43" ...
```

---

To generate the result you added in the example you could use this:

```
norm %>% 
  mutate(minutes = 60*as.numeric(hr)+as.numeric(min),
  group = floor(minutes/120)) %>% 
  mutate(label = paste0(group*2,":00-",group*2+2,":00" )) %>%
  group_by(email_address_hash, label) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread(label, n)
```

Which results in:

```
email_address_hash `10:00-12:00` `18:00-20:00` `20:00-22:00` `4:00-6:00` `6:00-8:00`  `8:00-10:00`
<fctr>             <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>       <int>        <int>
0004eca7...        1             NA            NA             1          NA           NA
00198ee5...        NA            NA            1             NA           2           NA
35c0ef2c...        NA            1             NA            NA          NA            1
```

Allthought not exactly like you're output example. That is because I do not agree with the data structure you are looking for.

Comment: you separated the time into hh:mm:ss . I wanted something else. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Maybe if you try this script and look at the norm structure you can easily adapt to what you want. Otherwise please add an example of the result `data.frame` you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have edited the question according to your requirement. Please let me know if this makes sense to you